# Solving inverse problems with PyMC

Tags: python, probability, pymc, mcmc

Suppose we're given a prior on **X** (e.g. X ~ Gaussian) and a forward operator **y = f(x)**. Suppose further we have observed **y** by means of an experiment and that this experiment can be repeated indefinitely. The output **Y** is assumed to be Gaussian (Y ~ Gaussian) or noise-free (Y ~ Delta(observation)).

How to consistently update our subjective degree of knowledge about **X** given the observations? I've tried the following model with PyMC, but it seems I'm missing something:

```
from pymc import *

xtrue = 2                        # this value is unknown in the real application
x = rnormal(0, 0.01, size=10000) # initial guess

for i in range(5):
    X = Normal('X', x.mean(), 1./x.var())
    Y = X*X                        # f(x) = x*x
    OBS = Normal('OBS', Y, 0.1, value=xtrue*xtrue+rnormal(0,1), observed=True)
    model = Model([X,Y,OBS])
    mcmc = MCMC(model)
    mcmc.sample(10000)

    x = mcmc.trace('X')[:]       # posterior samples
```

The posterior is not converging to **xtrue**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The functionality purposed by @user1572508 is now part of PyMC under the name `stochastic_from_data()` or `Histogram()`. The solution to this thread then becomes:

```
from pymc import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xtrue = 2 # unknown in the real application
prior = rnormal(0,1,10000) # initial guess is inaccurate
for i in range(5):
  x = stochastic_from_data('x', prior)
  y = x*x
  obs = Normal('obs', y, 0.1, xtrue*xtrue + rnormal(0,1), observed=True)

  model = Model([x,y,obs])
  mcmc = MCMC(model)
  mcmc.sample(10000)

  Matplot.plot(mcmc.trace('x'))
  plt.show()

  prior = mcmc.trace('x')[:]
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that your function, $y = x^2$, is not one-to-one.  Specifically, because you lose all information about the sign of X when you square it, there is no way to tell from your Y values whether you originally used 2 or -2 to generate the data. If you create a histogram of your trace for X after just the first iteration, you will see this:[image: histogram of trace after first iteration]

This distribution has 2 modes, one at 2 (your true value) and one at -2.  At the next iteration, x.mean() will be close to zero (averaging over the bimodal distribution), which is obviously not what you want.

Comment: I know f(x) isn't a bijection, it was chosen because of that specific reason. I can't see any argument for MCMC to fail with this input distribution, as far as I know, MCMC is able to sample complex multi-modal distributions.

Comment: Oh, I understood your point, the problem is in how I update the prior. By simply using pos.mean() and pos.var() I'm assuming a unimodal solution. How would you solve this problem for finding both 2 and -2?

Comment: In other words, how to represent non-parametric distributions with PyMC? Given the trace, produce a PDF that matches the histogram.

Comment: I've encountered that same problem before.  I used a kernel density estimator to create a nonparametric prior that I could update.  It's kind of slow, but it seems to work well enough for simple problems.  Here's a gist using your example: https://gist.github.com/jcrudy/5911624

Comment: Kernel density estimation works fine for multimodal distributions.  Check out its wikipedia page, and particularly this example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Comparison_of_1D_histogram_and_KDE.png.  In short, although the kernel is gaussian, the resulting distribution estimate, which is a weighted sum of location shifted gaussian kernels, need not be.  The method you linked to assumes a gaussian distribution, if I'm understanding it correctly.  You would have to modify it for a bimodal distribution, and would need to specify a parametric form for that bimodal distribution.